# Natural Isomorphism $(V\otimes W)^*\cong V^*\otimes W^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products

According to Wikipedia, there exists a natural isomorphism $(V\otimes W)^*\cong V^*\otimes W^*$ for finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$. I can show that given bases $v_i$, $i\in I$ and $w_j$, $j\in J$ with dual bases $v^*_i$, $i\in I$ and $w^*_j$, $j\in J$, an isomorphism is given by

$$
(V\otimes W)^*\ni D \mapsto \sum_{I\times J} v^*\otimes w^* D(v\otimes w).
$$
 I feel like the choice of bases above makes this isomorphism not natural. However, I am really bad at understanding "naturality".

Comment: I'm curious to see the precise wording on Wikipedia: where did you find that statement?

Comment: On the German Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensorprodukt#Nat.C3.BCrliche_Homomorphismen. In this short section you easily find the above identity. Naturality is not mentioned anymore in the next, but I assumed, given the section title (you might guess: "Natürliche Homomorphismen" means "natural homomorphisms").

Comment: Oh, thanks! I assume that "endlichdimensionale" means finite-dimensional, right? You omitted that part from your question!

Comment: That is true, I apologise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a bit tricky. There are two functors $F,G : \mathsf{Vect}^{op} \times \mathsf{Vect}^{op} \to \mathsf{Vect}$ given respectively by
$$F(V,W) = V^* \otimes W^*, \quad G(V,W) = (V \otimes W)^*$$
(and correspondingly on linear maps). Then there is a [natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) $\varphi : F \to G$, in components:
$$\varphi_{V,W} : V^* \otimes W^* \to (V \otimes W)^*,$$
given by $\varphi(\alpha,\beta) : v \otimes w \mapsto \alpha(v) \beta(w)$. In other words, if $f : V \to V'$ and $g : W \to W'$ are linear map,
$$(f \otimes g)^* \circ \varphi_{V', W'}  = \varphi_{V,W} \circ (f^* \otimes g^*).$$

This map $\varphi_{V,W}$ is always injective; thus, when both $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, it's an isomorphism (because of dimension considerations: $\dim(V^* \otimes W^*) = \dim(V) \dim(W) = \dim((V \otimes W)^*)$). If both are infinite-dimensional, then $\varphi_{V,W}$ is not an isomorphism.

To explicitly compute the inverse of $\varphi_{V,W}$ when both are finite-dimensional, you need to choose bases of $V$ and $W$ (and the inverse is indeed the map you have constructed). This is kinda weird, because we know the inverse exists without talking about bases, but it doesn't seem possible to actually write it down without bases.

Comment: This clears most of my confusion. However, since I already started talking about it, what does natural mean? I really know almost nothing about category theory, but I guess it means that $\phi$ is functoral: $\phi_{X,Y}\circ f=F\circ \phi_{V,W}$ for any homomorphism $f\colon V^*\otimes W^*\to X^*\otimes Y^*$ and for some function $F=F(f)$. Is this correct? Any more I need to know about $F$? Is this really the way to check naturality or is there an easier (not to say more natural) way to understand the naturality of your $\phi$?

Comment: @Bananach https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation Basically here it means that if you have linear maps $f : V \to V'$ and $g : W \to W'$, then $(f \otimes g)^* \circ \varphi_{V', W'}  = \varphi_{V,W} \circ (f^* \otimes g^*)$.

Comment: So to check for naturality of your $\varphi$, we need to know that we identify maps $V'^*\otimes W'^*\to V^*\otimes W^*$ with maps $(V'\otimes W')^*\to (V\otimes W)^*$? via $(f^*\otimes g^*)\mapsto (f\otimes g)^*$)? In other words, strictly speaking not $\varphi$ alone is natural, but $\varphi$ together with the above identification of linear maps is natural. ($\varphi$ together with this identification is a functor, which is naturally isomorphic to the identity functor)

Comment: @Bananach That's not quite right. You have two functors $\mathsf{Vect}^{op} \to \mathsf{Vect}$: $F:(V,W) \mapsto V^* \otimes W^*$ and $G:(V,W) \mapsto (V \otimes W)^*$ (and correspondingly on linear maps). $\varphi$ is a natural transformation from $F$ to $G$. Walk through the definitions of functor and natural transformations applied to this situation to see what's going on.

Comment: @Bananach To clarify, $f^* \otimes g^* = F(f \otimes g)$ and $(f \otimes g)^* = G(f \otimes g)$ are not *identified*, but there is a (natural) commutative square linking the two, and the other two maps in the commutative square are isomorphisms.

Comment: This helps a lot! When I tried to match our situation to the definitions before, I assumed $F$ was the identity on a Category of spaces of the form $V^*\otimes W^*$ and $\varphi$ was the natural transformation to this identity functor.