# Isomorphism between $(V^*)^{\otimes k}$ and $(V^{\otimes k})^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

> Is there a natural isomorphism between $(V^*)^{\otimes k}$ and $(V^{\otimes k})^*$ ?

I don't know how to proceed and will appreciate a hint. Thanks!

$(V^{\otimes k})^*$ is a vector space and so is isomorphic to $(V^{\otimes k})$. Now, I need to show isomorphism between $(V^*)^{\otimes k}$  and  $(V^{\otimes k})$. I can't proceed beyond this point.

Here dual of a vector space $W$ is $W^*$.

Comment: Yes, but that's certainly not how you go about it; there isn't a natural isomorphism between a vector space and its dual. Try to find a way to pair elements of $(V^{\ast})^{\otimes k}$ with $V^{\otimes k}$.

Comment: Not literally a duplicate, but reading this question and its answer should help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487482/natural-isomorphism-v-otimes-w-cong-v-otimes-w.  Note that you need $V$ to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am think I am getting this wrong but for $k=2$, if $\{v_i\otimes v_j\}$ is the basis of $V\otimes V$ and $\{v_i^*\otimes v_j^*\}$ is the basis of $V*\otimes V$, then can we not send $v_i\otimes v_j$ to $v_i^*\otimes v_j^*$? The map I am thinking of is $f(a)=f(\sum a_{ij} v_i\otimes v_j)=\sum a_{ij}v_i^*\otimes v_j^*$

Comment: The above map is injective and linear. Also, $\dim (V^*\otimes V^*)=n^2=\dim(V\otimes V)*$ so it is an isomorphism.

Comment: That map isn't natural; if you pick a different basis you'll get a different map. One way to say what "natural" means is that you can talk about it without choosing a basis.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I see. I am not really able to think of  a natural isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, there's a natural dual pairing $V \otimes V^{\ast} \to k$ ($k$ the underlying field). Apply the dual pairing $n$ times to get a natural pairing

$$V^{\otimes n} \otimes (V^{\ast})^{\otimes n} \to k.$$

This gives a natural map $(V^{\ast})^{\otimes n} \to (V^{\otimes n})^{\ast}$. Can you show it's an isomorphism (when $V$ is finite-dimensional)?